# Mapped type in a class

Tags: typescript

I have a union of keys that must be present in an object:

```
type Keys = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'
```

And I need to declare a class that contains those keys:

```
class WithKeys {
  [key in Keys]: string
}
```

Now the problem is, I can't define anything else in this class. Not even a constructor! Otherwise I get an error "A mapped type can not declare properties or methods". Obviously it won't work like this either, because the values are not definitely initialized.

If it was a type, I'd just do an intersection with the rest of the fields. But there's no such thing as class intersections. So how do I go from here?

Comment: That's invalid TS even without defining any extra.  Mapped types are self-contained; they cannot be made "part of" a class or interface.  Don't you see [an error](https://tsplay.dev/NDVY4W) with that code as is?  If not, something weird is going on with your environment.  If so, you might want to [edit] so as to say something like "this doesn't work at all, how can I get this behavior"?

Comment: That's what I said, either way it's an error. So how do I include a mapped type in a class? There's no mechanism to extend a class from a type.

Comment: @riv `implements`?

Comment: Hmm, you say "I can't do anything else, **otherwise** I get an error...". If you get an error no matter what, then "otherwise" isn't applicable.  If you mean "Now the problem is, this doesn't work.  I get an error..." then please [edit] to say that.

Comment: (see prev comment) Assuming you do that edit... what would you like to see happen in the class with regard to property initialization?  Do you want to pick a default string to assign to all of them (like `""`)?  Or do you want to choose each one separately?

Comment: @VLAZ if a class implements something, you still have to duplicate the field declarations, which leads back to the same problem.

Comment: @jcalz the question does say that the example does not compile, maybe in not the most obvious way though. And as for initialization, that's what the constructor is for, I'd loop over the keys and initialize them with something.

Comment: @riv you'd have to do it anyway because you need to assign values. At least if you use `strictNullChecks`. You cannot magically give default values when implementing a type. You can just "inherit" the fields without needing to assign any values if `strictNullChecks` is off, though. Is that the case? Or are you supposed to also give defaults and if so - how would you pick them?

Comment: "*I'd loop over the keys and initialize them with something*" types are compile-time constructs. You want to go from a compile-time thing to a concrete run-time thing which isn't possible. You can do *the opposite* but that's not really what you asked. I suggest focusing your question on what you actually want to achieve and avoid [an XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: @riv I don't see where you say it doesn't compile as written.  You say "it won't work like this either", but apparently only because "the values are not definitely initialized", which is not the problem with the code as written (you could make them optional and it still wouldn't compile like that). Could you please [edit] the question to be more obvious? Or I'd be happy to do it for you.  Or, could you articulate why it's better to leave it like this than for it to be edited?  Maybe there's some advantage to the current phrasing that I'm not seeing?

Comment: A mapped type can use `[...]?: ...` to have optional values. I could use that if I'm not definitely assigning something.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that. Because type cannot use as value

do this instead

```
type Keys = 'foo' | 'bar' | 'baz'

type T = {
  [Property in Keys]: string
}

class WithKeys implements T {
  foo: string
  bar: string
  baz: string
}
```

Comment: But then if you add anything to the type, you have to go and correct every class definition, that sounds like an anti pattern?

Comment: It is for this purpose that implements have been added. This is not an anti-pattern

Comment: Okay so what if Keys has hundreds of items? How do you imagine the class looking? Or if it's a generic construct such as `Exclude`?

Comment: Even if there are 100000000000000 keys, each one must be shown in the class.
This is because a class must know what it is doing when it creates an object.
  Types are a concept specific to Typescript and are removed when compiling to javascript
If you convert `const object: { foo?: string } = {}` to javascript
`const object = {}` will be.
  If it is created from the class in the form above, in the case of `const object = new WithKeys()`, it will be in the form `{ foo: undefined, bar: undefined, baz: undefined }`. If you do not specify the keys in the class, you will not get such a result